# How to change Bootstrap progress bar width with {{$percentage}} variable value in style Laravel?

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

Im working on some project where I want to show PERCENTAGE of marks obtained with progress bar.

Im having value in percentage and I want to pass this value in style: "width:{{$percentage}}" so that progress bar width changes according to marks obtained, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

Please see $percentage is at the end of table data->**{{round($percentage, 2)}}**

```
<tr>
                                  <td>1</td>
                                  <td>{{$q->name}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$totalQuestions}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$attemptQuestions}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$userCorrectAnswer}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$userWrongAnswer}}</td>
                                  <td>{{round($percentage, 2)}}</td>
                                </tr>

                                @endforeach
                                
                              </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <p>
                                <strong>Percentage</strong> <span class="pull-right small muted">{{round($percentage, 2)}}</span>
                                
                            </p>

                             <div class="progress">

                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{$percentage}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width : {{$percentage}}">
                              
                                <span class="sr-only">{{round($percentage, 2)}} Obtained</span>

                              </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `%` to the style like so.

```html
style="width : {{$percentage}}%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leaving the progress-bar div without any contents? Try putting the  outside of the div